# models relationship question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a model `Post` and a model `User` where a post belongs to a User and a User has many posts . I would like to have me returned my friends posts .

After "grabbing" my friends with `@friends = current_user.friends` , i have to browse through all my @friends ( who of course are also User-s ) and have them return a array in a variable that contains the most recent 20 of my friends posts and i don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sort you can do:

```
array_posts = {}
@friends.each do |friend|
  array_posts[friend.name] = friend.posts.sort_by(&:created_at)
end
```

array_post will have for each of your friends their lists of posts sorted by their created_at attribute.